# Change selected text color with css

Tags: css, wordpress

Good day, I'm having some difficulties trying to figure out how to change a specific text in a sentence.

**I have the following text:**

Welcome to Strongest Legend

**What i have in code:**

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>  Welcome to Strongest Legend </strong></h1>
```

So i have tried changing the to code to following :

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>  Welcome to Strongest</strong></h1><h1 id="legend"><strong> Legend </strong></h1>
```

I have a plugin installed named Custom CSS where i put all the css code, i have tried editing the "Legend" by its id but it doesn't work.

Can someone please explain what am i doing wrong?

I want the following css code to take effect.

```
.legend {
 color: #5E5E5E; 
}
```

I have it posted in appearances -> custom CSS.

**Sorry, i forgot that posting links on SO is forbidden.**

Comment: is it on you local computer or can we see it live? Are you using a template or is it something custom made? if it is a template, you should have template settings where you can write the css code, without the use of external plugins. Also, when you are logged in, and on the homepage, you have the Customize option where you can write css.

Comment: Do u want to change the text value of legend to somrhtng else?

Comment: do you want to change color of legend text?

Comment: @charankumar yes, i've updated the post.

Comment: i think css is overridden, try using !important for #legend

Comment: @GautamNaik yes i want to change the color of legend and some other text, but legend will be a exampe of how to change the other text that i need . P.S i've updated the post with website link.

Comment: <h1 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to Strongest<span style="font-weight:bold !important;"> Legend</h1> try this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

use **#legend** not **.legend**

> You are using Id not class

Answer (score 0):

Your code is like that,

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>  Welcome to Strongest</strong></h1><h1 id="legend"><strong> Legend </strong></h1>
```

Now, you apply the css like that,

```html
h1#legend {
  color: #5E5E5E;
 }
```

Thanks!!